# How to read a file word by word?

Tags: c, function

I am confused that how to give break line after every word which is present in a file.

**Words in text file**

```
Name    Date of birth     <----  I put this in code  
John    02\02\1999        <----  I want to jump to this line
```

**I want this**

```
Here is your: Name
Here is your: Date of Birth
```

**But it is giving me this**

```
Here is your: N 
Here is your: a 
Here is your: m 
Here is your: e
```

**And I don't know how to get it.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    FILE * fr = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt","r");
    char ch;

    if(fr != NULL){
        while(!feof(fr)){
            ch = fgetc(fr);
            printf("Here is your %c\n: ", ch);
        }
        fclose(fr);
    }
    else{
        printf("Unable to read file.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf` with the `%s` format?

Comment: Also please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: You're asking for a character at a time and that's what you're getting.

Comment: how are words stored in your file ?

Comment: I want word like name, date of birth etc which is present in text file. Not each character one by one.

Comment: Horizontally stored 'Name Date of birth ID card number Phone number Address Account Fixing year Deposit amount'

Comment: There are 3 words in `date of birth `. It seems that you want to print line by line, not word by word.

Comment: So, you want to group together some words into a sentence, but if they are all on the same line, what should the program use to be able to tell where one sentence ends and the next one begins? The first letter of the word being in upper case signals the start of the next sentence?

Comment: Yeah. Now I want a group of some words like 'Date of Birth' and then if it finishes then another like ID card number etc. The text file contains horizontal words not vertically.

Comment: In the file is it written as `Date of birth` or as `Date of Birth`? If only the first letter in every word in all the sentences is in uppercase (like in `Date of birth`) it is possible to do something to separate sentences automatically, however the if that is not the case, such as in `Date of Birth` then there is no way to detect were one sentence ends and the next one begins, the only option would be to count the words while known previously how many words each sentence will have to group them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `while` loop instead of immediately printing the character that you read, store the `char` in a `char` array. Add an `if` statement that does a comparison that checks if the read `char` is a space character. If it is you should print the stored array and set the index of the array back to 0.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    FILE * fr = fopen("file.txt","r");
    char ch[100];
    int index = 0;

    if(fr != NULL){
        while((ch[index] = fgetc(fr)) != EOF){
            //printf("%c\n", ch[index]);
            if(ch[index] == ' ') {
                ch[index] = '\0';
                printf("Here is your: %s\n", ch);
                index = 0;
            }
            else {
                index++;
            }
        }
        fclose(fr);
    }
    else{
        printf("Unable to read file.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is giving me Here is your : 11. I don't 11s in text file.

Comment: @NatashaBibi I made an edit. It should work now.

Comment: It worked but not like I want means it is giving me Here is your: Date , Here is your: of, Here is your: Birth. I want this to be Here is your Date of Birth.

Comment: Did you get what I am talking about. Please read the question again if it is not clear to you.

Comment: It's clear. If you want that then you have to somehow distinguish groups of words in the file. The way it's currently implemented makes it impossible for the code to determine by itself which words should be grouped together.

Comment: Do you want me to remove some words and place words without spaces?

Comment: I'm not sure you mean. You can do any solution that you want. There just isn't a way to do what you're asking with the _current_ method the words are being stored.

Comment: Okay bro. Thank you for your support!

Comment: You could start each group of words with a capital letter to distinguish the groups or something like that. It depends on any restrictions that you have.

Comment: It is necessary to check if the first letter of the word is in uppercase, if it is then it is the start of the next sentence... It is the only way I can think of to group the words into sentences.

Comment: Hey, I made an array and put those words there. Here is question. If I want to move to the next line to fetch those values of related to name, DOB, etc. How would I do that to move to next row? I have also added details for you to check out.

Comment: You can check for  '\n' the same way the current code is checking for a space.

Comment: Could you just write. I wrote but confused.

Comment: What is your expected output of the data?

Comment: const char listings[8][51] = {"Name", "Date of birth"}; Now I want to fetch values of those names and DOB from text file. Because I put this in array and there are a lot of data of names and DOB so I can't put in code.

Comment: I think you should make a new question. Your actual question is changing a lot and I think it would be clearer to put this in a new question.

Comment: Okay I will put new question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the line of text of the file provided we can assume that if the first letter of the word is in uppercase then it is the start of the next sentence:

```
Name Date of birth ID card number Phone number Address Account Fixing year
```

And use this to divide the line into sentences.

So here is the code by Christopher changed to group the words into sentences:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){

    FILE * fr = fopen("file.txt","r");
    char ch[100];
    int index = 0;

    if(fr != NULL){
        while((ch[index] = fgetc(fr)) != EOF){
            if(index > 0 && ch[index-1] == ' ' && isupper(ch[index])) {
                ch[index-1] = '\0';
                printf("Here is your: %s\n", ch);
                ch[0] = ch[index];
                index = 1;
            }
            else {
                index++;
            }
        }
        ch[index] = '\0';
        printf("Here is your: %s\n", ch);
        fclose(fr);
    }
    else{
        printf("Unable to read file.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to read second row. Because I put those words in array and the values of those words are without spaces.